# Assign output directory with command

Tags: omnet++, veins

Is there an option to change output directory when run simulation with `./run -u Cmdevn`?

Thanks.
BR.
PZ.

Comment: What do you mean by *change output directory*?

Comment: Hi, I meant the location of the result files, e.g., *.vec, *.vci, and *.sca.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use:

```
./run -u Cmdevn --result-dir=/tmp/res
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! (sorry I don't have enough reputations to vote up)